# Why stored procedure returns wrong sum for each group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this query but `SUM(SUM(inv.ServicePrice)) over () as TotalRevenueAllServices`
return me the wrong sum. I actually want to get sum of all sums that I have done for each group but it returns wrong value.

```
Select top(3) s.ServiceName, Count(inv.fk_ServiceID) as TotalServicesCount, Sum(inv.ServicePrice) TotalServicesRevenue,
        SUM(SUM(inv.ServicePrice)) over () as TotalRevenueAllServices
        from Invoices inv
        inner join Services s
        on s.ServiceID= inv.fk_ServiceID
        group by inv.fk_ServiceID, s.ServiceName
        Order By ServiceName asc
```

Comment: share sample data with expected output

Comment: `SUM({expr}) OVER ()` is going to return the sum of every row in the table. Why would you want to `SUM` it again?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: Do you want the sum of just the `top 3` or of all groups?  Without sample data and results, your question is unclear.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Note to self: @ZoharPeled: Don't post an answer based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @FromDate date= '22/Nov/2017',
        @ToDate date= '24/Nov/2018'


        Set @ToDate= ISNULL(@ToDate, getdate());


        with MainTable
        as
        (
        Select top(3) s.ServiceName, Count(inv.fk_ServiceID) as TotalServicesCount, Sum(inv.ServicePrice) TotalServicesRevenue      
        from Invoices inv
        inner join Services s
        on s.ServiceID= inv.fk_ServiceID
        --where CAST(inv.EntryDateTime as DATE) between @FromDate and @ToDate
        group by inv.fk_ServiceID, s.ServiceName
        Order By ServiceName asc
        )
        select * , (select sum(totalservicesrevenue) from MainTable) 'AllServicesRevenue'
        ,          (select sum(TotalServicesCount) from MainTable) 'OverallServices'
                    from MainTable
```